# Asus N751JK temperature issues

Tags: temperature, overheating, asus-laptop

I got few months ago a a laptop, specifically a N751JK Asus laptop, I began to use it more frequently(recently) and I see that I get quite huge temperatures on it.
When I am browsing the internet / using Visual Studio I get around 60-65 °C and when I play games (CS:GO/Heartstone) I get around 90°C.
Also  have installed the latest drivers available for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a notebookcheck review the temperature issue is a known issue.

If its still under warranty you can always return it saying it unusable for heavy gaming because of the temperature rising too high and causing the hardware to throttle slowing down your games.

If warranty has run out, you can still do a few minor things to help but it probably wont solve the underlying issue.

1) Make sure its not placed on any cloth or non flat surface which interfere with airflow.
2) Use compressed air to remove any dust collected in the heatsinks or fans inside (may need to open it up to get it properly).
3) Purchase and use a laptop cooling pad.

Review here:
http://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-N751JK-T4144H-Notebook-Review.135510.0.html